# Adjust wardrobe sliding glass door

Tags: mirror, sliding-glass-door, wardrobe

I've just moved into a new house and there is a large sliding wardrobe where the doors are not straight. Having done some research it looks like there is some tweaking at the wheels that can be done to lift the side of each door up and down.

However, I don't seem to find an obvious way to adjust this from the top nor from the bottom. I've attached a couple of photos showing the top and bottom. Does anyone know how I can adjust this?

[image: Bottom wheel]

[image: Top wheel]

Comment: Look closely at the upper hanger - that plastic rod with the spring around it - is it threaded?

Comment: It's not. That's just a tensioner to keep the glider in the track. The height adjustment is at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hex bolt (1) appears to be an eccentric adjuster. Loosen that and swing the inner portion of the wheel, which acts as a ball bearing race (2). It might be near the end of its travel range, so use both wheels' adjustments as needed. The pivot for the assembly is up high (3).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I’m still unsure how that changes the height of the door. Do I move the wheel relative to that copper looking piece and then tighten the hex bolt?

Comment: I mentioned the fact that it's _eccentric_ (off center). This means that rotating it moves its actual center--in this case upward and downward--raising or lowering the door in opposition.